# Maximize this function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

For the following matrix

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
f1[x,y,z] & f2[x,y,z]\\
g1[x,y,z] & g2[x,y,z]\\
h1[x,y,z] & h2[x,y,z]
\end{pmatrix}
$$

with

```
f1[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 Sqrt[z]]^2)
g1[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 I Sqrt[z]]^2)
h1[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + Sqrt[z]]^2)

f2[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z]])
g2[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - x]])
h2[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - y]])
```

Now I want to optimise the value of:

```
P = f1[x,y,z] pos[1] + f2[x,y,z] pos[2]
```

where `pos[j]` returns the row corresponding to the highest value in column `j` . However, I don't know how to define `pos[j]`. I currently have

**MWE**

> pos[1] = Position[{f1[x,y,z], g1[x,y,z], h1[x,y,z]]}, Max[f1[x,y,z], g1[x,y,z], h1[x,y,z]]]
>
> pos[2] = Position[{f2[x,y,z], g2[x,y,z], h2[x,y,z]]}, Max[f2[x,y,z], g2[x,y,z], h2[x,y,z]]]
>
> Poptimized = Maximize[P, {x, y, z}]

But this is not working. This is since `pos[1]` and `pos[2]` return empty lists. I thought that wrapping it inside the `Maximize` would have it evaluate. I want something structured as follows:

```
Maximize[f1[x,y,z] pos[1] + f2[x,y,z] pos[2],{x,y,z}]
```

where `pos[1]` and `pos[2]` both also depend on `x,y,z` and so need to be optimised too.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `f1[x_,y_,z_] := ...`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo ...

Comment: `f2=g2=h2`?....

Comment: Does ArgMax do what you want?

Comment: $x\in Reals$ why do you need `Im[x]=0`   and so `f1[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-E^(2 Im[x]) Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 Sqrt[z]]^2)= f1[x_,y_,z_] := E^(-Abs[y Sqrt[1 - z] + 0.1 Sqrt[z]]^2)`

Comment: The functions are really just examples. The question is how to determine the position of max values for the maximization step

Comment: `pos[M_?MatrixQ, j_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{col = M[[All, j]]},
  M[[Position[col, Max[col]][[1, 1]]]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer but try this. Since all function has the same max value, how do you decide which function you choose? Mathematica chose the last one.

```
M = {{-x - y^2 - 2 z , x - y^2 + 2 z },
{-x - y - z^2, x + 2 y + z^2},
{-x - y - z^3, 2 x - y + z}};
```

> $M=\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -x-y^2-2 z & x-y^2+2 z \\
>  -x-y-z^2 & x+2 y+z^2 \\
>  -x-y-z^3 & 2 x-y+z \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
pos1 = First@Ordering[MaxValue[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ M[[All, 1]], -1]
pos2 = First@Ordering[MaxValue[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ M[[All, 2]], -1]

P = NMaximize[M[[1,1]] pos1 + M[[1,2]] pos2,{x, y, z}]
```

Comment: You are correct that each row has two columns. However, I am trying to find the maximum values in each column. Hence, for the above example, pos[1] looks for the row corresponding to the max value in column 1. That is `pos[1]=Ordering[MaxValue[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ func, -1]`.

Comment: I want to then determine the optimised value for `P = f1[x,y,z] pos[1] + f2[x,y,z] pos[2]`, where `f1[x,y,z] = x + y^2 + 2z` and `f2[x,y,z] = x + y + z^2`. Can I use your above code inside the `Maximize` function?

Comment: I want something structured as follows: `Maximize[f1[x,y,z] pos[1] + f2[x,y,z] pos[2],{x,y,z}]`. How can I define `pos[j]` such that it it takes performs the optimisation and returns the row position as described in the question?

Comment: These functions are unbounded above `f1[x,y,z] = x + y^2 + 2z` and `f2[x,y,z] = x + y + z^2` Can you edit the question with your real problem if it is not too complicated.

Comment: The actual functions i'm using are very lengthy. However `x, y, z` are all finite. Can you describe how `pos1` is defined please? It's correctly looking at column 1, but how is it looking for the MaxValue? (i.e. what values for `x,y,z` is it using to determine which is largest)

Comment: `MaxValue` only return max value of a function, `ArgMax` returns only `x,y,z` values that function takes max and `NMaximize` returns both `x,y,z` values and function value at those values.

Comment: If I change the definition of `P` to `P = NMaximize[pos1,{x, y, z}]` and I do `M[[All, 1]] /. P[[2]] // MatrixForm`, your value for `pos1` does not correspond to the largest value in `M[[All, 1]]`. Why is this?